# How do you autoload a directory in Silex

Tags: php, silex

If I have a directory of class files in /src/lib and I want them autoloaded, how do I do this with the latest version of Silex.

I don't really see any good documention other that loading services.

Comment: Do you use namespaced code that respects psr0, or you simply have a collection of classes in there?

Comment: It's now respecting the psr-0 conventions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The autoloading of silex is handled by [composer](http://getcomposer.org/). The [composer documentation on autoloading](http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload) goes into detail on what kinds of autoloading are possible.

It is recommended that you use a `psr-0` naming scheme for your files. But if you don't want to do that, you can also use classmap autoloading.

Here's an example with PSR-0, assuming the class `Foo\Bar` is in `src/Foo/Bar.php`:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "Foo": "src/" }
    }
}
```

For classmap, refer to the documentation linked above.

Comment: Added a trailing slash in the composer json file and this worked.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I ended up using the classmap autoload option as it seemed simpler for the application I'm building.